# Paste shapes transposed in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, paste, transpose, shapes

When I pasted cells transposed, the pictures were not pasted.

Is this normal for Excel?

If so is there any code or trick to get those pictures (which are column/row headers!) Transposed from the old row to the new column?

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys. Copy and paste object with cells is not working with transpose. So can anyone help with some vba code? (they are all in their own adjacent cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved- here is an addin to do it! US$10 My Excel Tools Spreadsheet image tools https://myexceltools.com/pages_spreadsheet_images/view_more_spreadsheet_image.htm

(need to paste in same sheet then move to aother sheet if required afaik)